# Why Ti:YAG laser do not work?

Tags: experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, laser

In my solid-state laser class we learned about Ti:saphire lasers and that the emission and absorption spectra of Ti:YAG are similar. My professor left an open quation whether they are useful lasers. As I did not find any papers on Ti:YAG Lasers, I would say they are not useful. Unfortunately I cannot figure out why. Can anyone help me?